# How can i implement multiple smart-contract in a single chain-code using java?

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

is it possible to implement multiple smart contracts in a single chain-code package in hyper ledger fabric 2.0? For example, I have two contracts Car Transfer and Money Transfer. Is it possible to have them in a single chain-code?

I was trying to implement two smart contracts namely  Car Transfer and Money Transfer. Now when I call the methods in Car transfer they work fine. but when I call the methods of Money Transfer it shows the error "Undefined contract method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although discussing Node.js chaincode, this answer also applies to your question:

[Failed to deploy multiple chaincode on same peer in hyperledger fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75768604/failed-to-deploy-multiple-chaincode-on-same-peer-in-hyperledger-fabric/75801305#75801305)

The principles are the same regardless of the smart contract implementation language (Go, Node, Java). For a Java implementation, only one of the smart contracts within the chaincode package can be the default smart contract (marked with the [@Default](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-java/main/api/org/hyperledger/fabric/contract/annotation/Default.html) annotation), and accessed using only the chaincode name. All others must be referred to using their chaincode *and* contract name (defined in the [@Contract](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-java/main/api/org/hyperledger/fabric/contract/annotation/Contract.html) annotation).

See the Fabric samples for [examples of annotation usage](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/628331d1a2c7885c4c6cfcf626b7e63ac98f7e2f/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-java/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/samples/assettransfer/AssetTransfer.java#L26-L39).

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. just added @Default to the one Contract, and it worked.